# Windows only successfully wakes up from sleep mode about 2/3rds of the time

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, troubleshooting, sleep

On my Vista laptop, when it goes into sleep mode (for low power, or manually being put into sleep mode, it happens regardless of how), about 1 in 3 times it won't wake up properly from sleep mode, and just display a black screen. The only option is to hold the power button to turn it off by holding the power button, and turning it back on again.

(And yes, I have moved the mouse, pressed keyboard buttons and stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Usually the culprit in these cases are buggy video drivers or an older BIOS. If you are not on the latest versions of these, I suggest that you update them and give it another shot.

Also, install Vista SP2 and the latest updates if you have not.

Comment: I have both these at the latest version (but it's a Dell laptop - hasn't been updated from what came on the discs), and Vista SP2.

Comment: Have you looked on the actual hardware vendor's website instead of Dell's for the drivers?